# ng-include seems to do nothing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/5z7bX/

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/newTrack.html">
  <h1>New Track </h1>
  <p>Hello there</p>
</script>
<div id="overlay" closemodal></div>
<div id="modal"><a id="closeModal" closemodal></a>
    <div id="modalContent" ng-include src="/newTrack.html"></div>
</div>
```

I would expect the following result:

```
<div id="overlay" closemodal></div>
<div id="modal"><a id="closeModal" closemodal></a>
    <div id="modalContent" ng-include src="/newTrack.html">
       <h1>New Track </h1>
       <p>Hello there</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But nothing seems to happen. Really I am trying to render the template from inside a custom directive, after tracking it down for a while, it appears I can't get `ng-include` to working even in its most simple form. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Fiddle Options, add `<body ng-app>`

> src: If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in quotes, e.g.,`src="'myPartialTemplate.html'"`. -- [ngInclude docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude)

So `ng-include src="'/newTrack.html'"`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fktwn/)

Comment: its the quotes inside quotes that got me.

Comment: I'm sorry I am still struggling with this problem. If you want to help I opened a second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028594/angular-scope-confusion