# angular scope confusion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So lets say I am writing a custom directive that loads a template into a div. My custom directive is called `loadClickedTpl`. When `loadClickedTpl` is clicked it should read the attribute and load the template into `#target`.

So far my html looks something like this:

```
 <html np-app="mymodule">
      <head>...</head>
      <body>

           <a loadClickedTpl tplSrc="myTpl" > Click Me to load template </a>

           <div id="target" ng-include src="clickedTpl"></div>

           <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTpl">
                <h1>Loaded</h1>
           </script>

      </body>
 </html>
```

The problem is setting the `clickedTpl` var to point to the template. If its done in the html like so `<div id="target" ng-include src="'myTpl'"></div>` it works fine, doing it programmatically is proving to be a challenge. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
angular.module('loadATpl').directive 'loadClickedTpl', ->
     (scope, element, attrs) ->
           element.bind 'click', -> 
                # does not work
                scope.clickedTpl = attrs.tplSrc

                # also does not work
                angular.injector(['ng']).invoke ($rootScope) ->
                       $rootScope.clickedTpl = attrs.tplSrc

                # obviously does not work
                clickedTpl = atts.tplSrc

angular.module('mymodule', ['loadATpl'])
```

The click binding does work, but that is were it ends.

Comment: Don't call `angular.injector` as that will create a new injector.  Rather, inject `$injector` into your directive.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14743553/215945  If you want access to `$rootScope`, you can just inject it into your directive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the working sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/8BNYr9J8g6tRLMo8VdPi?p=preview

You need to use attrs as 'load-clicked-tpl' (hyphenated expression) for angular
directives.

Comment: Ok, that sort of works. When its a separate module like in my example it stops though. http://plnkr.co/edit/IsW1Yf6Ye8HuROO7KMVW

Comment: You have to put dependency even if it is empty, try: `angular.module('loader', [])`

Comment: Turns out it was a more complex scope problem `angular.element(document).scope()` ended up saving me. That and you gave me a big nudge.