# ng-include don't include a partial view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a probleme with ng-include this code doesn't work and i don't find where is the error

```
<select name="select" id="select" class='input-large' ng-model="selectedbien">
                                        <option value='dz'>dz</option>
                                        <option value='fr'>fr</option>

                                        </select>
```

and `<section ng-include src="partial/selectedbien.html"></section>`

any help to find the problem please :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-include seems to do nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027701/ng-include-seems-to-do-nothing)

Answer (score 2):

It shall be

```
<section ng-include="'partial/selectedbien.html'"></section>
```

or

```
<ng-include src="'partial/selectedbien.html'"></ng-include>
```

Do not forget the quotes around URL - `ng-include` tries to interpret argument as angular.js expression, so you may change URL dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include your `template` directly then you need to add `''` to your path like

```
src="'partial/selectedbien.html'"
```

It seems you are trying to add path dynamically from your dropdown selection then you need to concatenation your model with your path like

```
src="'partial/' + selectedbien + '.html'"
```

Check the <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bYtv59kaLYPdFm25tppw?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: yes i wanna to add path dynamically from dropdown selection , but it doesn't work too ! with src="'partial/' + selectedbien + '.html'"

Comment: i dont know why the code doesn't work ! perhaps because i have others angularJS codes in my page !

Comment: console ! do you mean browser ?